# iOS - UILabel insets to zero is not worling

Tags: ios

I'm following the tutorial https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/08/04/swift-extending-uilabel/ because I want to remove the padding in the label inside.

The code seems very useful but I don't to make it work:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class EdgeInsetLabel: UILabel {
    var textInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero {
        didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
    }
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, 
        limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
        let insetRect = bounds.inset(by: textInsets)
        let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: insetRect, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
        let invertedInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -textInsets.top,
            left: -textInsets.left,
            bottom: -textInsets.bottom,
            right: -textInsets.right)
        return textRect.inset(by: invertedInsets)
    }
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: textInsets))
    }
}

extension EdgeInsetLabel {
    @IBInspectable
    var leftTextInset: CGFloat {
        set { textInsets.left = newValue }
        get { return textInsets.left }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var rightTextInset: CGFloat {
        set { textInsets.right = newValue }
        get { return textInsets.right }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var topTextInset: CGFloat {
        set { textInsets.top = newValue }
        get { return textInsets.top }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var bottomTextInset: CGFloat {
        set { textInsets.bottom = newValue }
        get { return textInsets.bottom }
    }
}
```

The result:
[image]

## What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The insets are based on the Font --- ***NOT*** on individual characters:

[image]

So, using the default system font in a `UILabel`, add a few other characters:

[image]

If you want to clip the background to the bounding box of an individual character, you'll need to use `Text Kit` functions. Here's a good place to start: [Using Text Kit to Draw and Manage Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html)

Answer (score 0):

use `myLabel.sizeToFit()` to remove any *removable space* around the label.

Comment: Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the overriding `textRect(forBounds:)` part inside the `EdgeLabel` subclass:

```
override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
    let insetRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, textInsets)
    let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: insetRect, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
    let invertedInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -textInsets.top,
            left: -textInsets.left,
            bottom: -textInsets.bottom,
            right: -textInsets.right)
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textRect, invertedInsets)
}
```

Comment: I added but nothing changed.